# BS4 How to get the text from [<td >1</td>]

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-table

Running into problems to get the text from [1]. I have the below code

```
url = "C:\\local.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
NoFall = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"Kendo_Table1535711951642"})
for AuxCopy in NoFall:
    product = AuxCopy.find('table').find_all('tr')
    for tr in product:
        td = tr.find_all('td', {"data-label":"Fallen Behind Days"})
        print(td)
```

The code is giving me the below output from the HTML

```
[]
[]
[<td class="ng-binding ng-scope nowrap" data-colid="FallenBehindDays" data-label="Fallen Behind Days" title="1">1</td>]
[<td class="ng-binding ng-scope nowrap" data-colid="FallenBehindDays" data-label="Fallen Behind Days" title="0">0</td>]
[<td class="ng-binding ng-scope nowrap" data-colid="FallenBehindDays" data-label="Fallen Behind Days" title="6">6</td>]
[<td class="ng-binding ng-scope nowrap" data-colid="FallenBehindDays" data-label="Fallen Behind Days" title="1">1</td>]
```

If I use td.text to get the numbers between `<td > </td>` it gives me the below error

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I'm trying to get only the numbers listed as follows

```
1
0
6
1
```

or find the largest number from the list in this case `6`

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by doing the following and the output is 6

```
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
NoFall = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"Kendo_Table1535711951642"})
max_value = None
for AuxCopy in NoFall:
    product = AuxCopy.find('table').find_all('tr')
    for tr in product:
        td = tr.find('td', {"data-label":"Fallen Behind Days"})
        if td is not None:
            if max_value is None or int(td.text) > max_value: max_value = int(td.text)
print(max_value)
```